# Does the absolute Galois group act transitively  on the trees with 3  terminal vertices?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi everyone. My question is about the absolute 
Galois group action on the set of the Grothendieck dessins.
The dessins I am interested in are trees with 
only one vertex of valency more then 2. 
(I don't know if there is a generally accepted term 
in graph theory. Starlike trees?).
What exactly is known about them?
Is the action transitive, at least for 
trees with 3  terminal vertices 
(with the same valency lists)?

EDIT: I see some clarification is necessary.
In fact, I consider the alternating dessins, 
so there are two valency lists for each of them.
(It is convenient to assume that the "center" is 
always, say, black). As Will Savin pointed out, 
a dessin with rotational symmetry cannot turn into
one with less symmetry. I confess I missed this 
obvious fact, but certainly this is not what I had 
in mind. The question was actually about *nontrivial*
obstacles to transitivity. (I know there are some for 
general trees).

Then, "what is known" part of the question. The best answer 
would be a long list of references.

Comment: clean dessins, or alternating black and white vertices?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the transitivity were known, just because there are not very many methods for proving things of that kind.

Answer (score 1):

No. The automorphism group of a dessin is the automorphism group of that covering, and is thus Galois-invariant. Choose a tree that has 3-fold rotational symmetry, and a tree with the same valency list that does not. Then these two trees are not Galois conjugate.

The smallest example is, for clean dessins, a 7-vertex symmetric tree and any other 7-vertex tree, and for alternating desins, a 10-vertex symmetric tree and any other 10-vertex tree with white terminal vertices.

Comment: daseins = Heidegger's drawings?

Comment: Fixed, thus unfortunately ruining the joke.